# LINQ C# select multiple columns by names in arrays

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to select columns by names or indexes, which are stored in array?

```
String[] columnsWhichINeed = new String[] { "column1", "column2" };

DataColumn[] aCols = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
          .Where(c => c.ColumnName.NEEDSOMEMAGICHERE;
          .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType))
          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use `Contains()` method like

```
.Where(c => columnsWhichINeed.Contains(c.ColumnName));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `Contains()`:

```
DataColumn[] aCols = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
      .Where(c => columnsWhichINeed.Contains(c.ColumnName))
      .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType))
      .ToArray();
```

unless you need to do case-insensitive string matching, in which case you'll need `Any()`:

```
DataColumn[] aCols = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
      .Where(c => columnsWhichINeed.Any(c2 => string.Compare(c.ColumnName, c2, true) == 0))
      .Select(c => new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType))
      .ToArray();
```